# How can I play continuous music in the background when my iPhone app is running?

Tags: iphone

I want to run light music (non-stop) when user is running my application actively. When user exits my application, then the music will be stopped automatically. I tried the following code to execute continuous music play (that is, play the music on a loop). But it doesn't actually loop; it ends the music once said music is completed.

```
- (void) PlayLoopMusic {
    NSString* path;
    NSURL* url;
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player setVolume: 0.030];
    [player setDelegate: self];

    // Start playing it while starting the game ...
    [player play];
}
```

Could someone please suggest methods to achieve looping, continuous music?

Comment: please have a way to turn off the music.  most people get very annoyed by apps (and especially web pages) that play music they can't turn off.

Comment: Ofcourse, i do have ...Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't had an opportunity to test this yet, but have you tried setting the `numberOfLoops` property to a negative value? The [AVAudioPlayer API docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/numberOfLoops) indicate that this is the correct way to get the sound to loop indefinitely.

Comment: Excellent. numberOfLoops added as -1, and it works continuously.

Answer (score 2):

set,

player.numberOfLoops = -1;